# Cocos2d Background image not showing properly on retina simulator and devices

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, background, cocos2d-iphone

I have implemented below code in cocos2d for showing background image and this code is working fine except in Retina devices. Background images is not scaled or set properly. It is working fine on iPad 2 with IOS 6.0 but not on Retina iPad (3) 6.0 and Retina simulators. I have even tried samples from github and ray wonder -samples. All codes have same issues. Did anybody face same kind of issue ?

```
  CCSprite *bg ;
  bg =  [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"GameBGiPad1.png"];
  bg.anchorPoint =   CGPointZero;
  [self addChild:bg z:-2];
```

I have included below lines to enable retina display and also added image with name "GameBGiPad1-hd.png" but it is showing black background on retina after adding below code:-

Also included below code in app delegate:-

```
if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");
```

Both images are not part of sprite sheet but placed in images folder.

Answer (score 2):

Cocos2d 1.0 : Not supports iPad retina display.

Cocos2d 2.0 : Use below naming convention.

For iPad retina you need to put image with extension -ipadhd.png

```
   GameBG.png          - For iPhone  
   GameBG-hd.png       - For iPhone HD
   GameBG-ipad.png     - For iPad  
   GameBG-ipadhd.png   - For iPad HD
   GameBG-iphone5hd    - For iPhone5
```

Comment: I have setup cocos2d 2.0 version and now image background issue is solved. One more related question:-

 I have included all images files with names as you suggested but still not clear about using/calling them . 

Will it pick HD files on iphone and ipad itself, even if only write below line for showing background image or will i have to specify exact filename (like on ipad retina :GameBGiPad1-ipadhd.png)

1   bg =  [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"GameBGiPad1.png"];

or 

2   bg =  [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"GameBGiPad1-ipadhd.png"];


Which line is write for retina ipad ?

Comment: yes...no need to check iphone or iPad, just put code spriteWithFile:@"image.png" and place image.png, image-hd.png, image-ipad.png and image-ipadhd.png in same folder.

Comment: GameBGiPad1.png for iPhone 4 inch and 4 inch Retina ?   GameBGiPad1-568.png, GameBGiPad1-568hd.png  ?

Comment: for iPhone 5, manually you need to handle in Cocos2d 2.0. I think its different question..post it in new question.